# Alternative to client side task runners in asp.net 5

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, gruntjs, azure-devops, onedrive

I have been using Visual Studio Team Services (was Visual Studio Online) for version control. As a backup i keep my project files on OneDrive and mapped the root work-spaces there. Soon after the launch of RC 1 and its support on Azure, we have started migrating all our projects to ASP.NET 5 and things have been really great, and i really love the GruntJS task runner for the client side development, but the issue with it is that the node modules create a highly nested folder structure which causes the OneDrive sync to fail.

The client side development happens in TypeScript and grunt is used just for bundling and minification purposes of the compiled JavaScript files. Since Web Optimizations is not the recommended method in ASP.NET 5 and i could not find any port for .NET Core

While searching for solutions i somewhere stumbled upon a link which said that OneDrive for Business does not have this limitation, we have Office 365 subscription for the organization and tried syncing the projects there, but failed as even OneDrive for business has this limitation.

Though there is a [UserVoice suggestion for this](https://onedrive.uservoice.com/forums/262982-onedrive/suggestions/6325774-enable-long-file-paths-aka-file-name-too-long-p), where the Microsoft Representative says that they are thinking about this, but till the time this gets implemented, i wanted to ask for alternatives to GruntJS for ASP.NET 5.

Since most of the application we build are single page enterprise apps where user opens the app during start of the workday and closes the tab at the end of day, rarely refreshing the app so we can live without optimizations for now, but just out of curiosity for consumer oriented application, are there any alternatives for GruntJS for ASP.NET 5.

**EDIT**

Points to be noted

- TFS Check in happens only when a code needs to be committed, but OneDrive sync happens continuously in the background automatically, in the event of a hardware crash or device getting lost (or any reason in the world stopping us from accessing the code), TFS won't be able to provide the code under development which was not committed. OneDrive saves us from those scenarios
- Check in happens mostly when a significant portion of assigned task in backlog is completed. In 50% of the cases it's 2-6 working hrs but in the rest half it can happen around 2-3 business days, worst case scenario is 5 days in case holidays happen in between.
- One drive allows us to stop syncing of selected folders available on live to local but there is no way we can stop sync of local folders to live
- Possibility of hardware failure is assumed to be once a year resulting in a loss of 5 working days and it's not an acceptable risk to loose the progress. (Just installation of visual studio enterprise with all features takes around 5-8 hrs on my development machine with 4th Gen Intel i5 2.9GHz 16GB ram, we have plans to upgrade our development machines with SSD and 64 GB of ram, but that's out of scope of question)
- If we weigh extra time spent in optimization tasks vs the risk of lost files, the optimization happens only when we push updates to production server which happens 1-3 times a month, every round of optimization tasks does not takes more than 10-15 minutes, so we can live with manually optimizing the files before production or not optimizing at all.
- Files like .gitignore and.csproj allows which files to sync to TFS not OneDrive, and my problem is not at all with TFS, we are perfectly happy with the way Check Ins are done and managed, once a code is committed, all the worries are resolved automatically, my worries is just for the uncommitted code.

**Summary**

I agree the problem has a highly specific nature, but it might be of help to future readers either looking for similar solutions or just to gain some more knowledge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things:

1. Team Foundation Services / Visual Studio online IS your source control solution, why would you need / want to back it up elsewhere?
2. I would probably exclude your node modules from your sync anyway. Your project configuration files will contain a list of the node modules you need, and if you wanted to move the app to a new machine or folder you'd just run `npm install` again to pull down the packages.

EDIT:

> TFS Check in happens only when a code needs to be committed, but
>   OneDrive sync happens continuously in the background automatically, in
>   the event of a hardware crash or device getting lost (or any reason in
>   the world stopping us from accessing the code), TFS won't be able to
>   provide the code under development which was not committed. OneDrive
>   saves us from those scenarios

This indicates that your check ins are likely too large or not frequent enough.
How often do you check in? How often does your hardware fail to the extent where you lose all files? Is this an acceptable risk?

> One drive allows us to stop syncing of selected folders available on live to local but there is no way we can stop sync of local folders
>   to live

And this is why you should be using TFS/VSO as the mechanism to control what files are stored in your source control repository. Systems like `.gitignore` or `.csproj` files exist for exactly this reason.

EDIT2:

I'm trying not to be too harsh and I agree this is a problem which could probably be solved in some specific way by OneDrive, but I'm trying to perform a SO equivalent of the [5 Whys](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/5_Whys).

You've said:

> TFS won't be able to provide the code under development which was not committed. OneDrive saves us from those scenarios

and

> Check in happens mostly when a significant portion of assigned task in backlog is completed. In 50% of the cases it's 2-6 working hrs but in the rest half it can happen around 2-3 business days, worst case scenario is 5 days in case holidays happen in between

Ok, so lets talk about that. You want to prevent loss of code if hardware fails, sure we all do. Looking at your figures 2-6 working hours seems reasonable, so you're looking at loosing 0.25 to 1 day (ballpark). I think the bigger issue is if people aren't checking in for 5 days. You've mentioned 5 days could be the worse case and only if holidays happen, so that's not 5 working days it's 2-3 business days worst case.

You've then said:

> Possibility of hardware failure is assumed to be once a year resulting in a loss of 5 working days

So, above you've said 2-6 hours for check-ins (with exceptions) but you've based your decision to come up with a solution for this problem based on an assumption of 5 working days. Above you've said 5 days (not working) only if holidays occur. So really your figures for risk are exaggerated.

Let's be more realistic and say you have a hardware failure once a year, and you lose 4 hours worth of work.
From OneDrive, how long would it take you restore this work? lets guess at say a few minutes to connect and download it, and perhaps half an hour to an hour to sort out conflicts (#optimism). So lets say a net saving of 3 hours...once a year...do you think this is reason enough to back up all code to a and offsite cloud provider?

You talk about time taken to re-install VS, but that's not relevant to backing files up to OneDrive, you'd need to do that irrespective.

To be honest, I think your fear of losing uncommitted code is blown out of proportion and I think your reaction is too. TFS and VSO offers functions like shelvesets which can be used for just this kind of situation.

As an enterprise developer too, I do understand the concern, but normally you'd cover this by working on a machine with a RAID array or similar.

I think you should re-assess you check in policy and your assessment of the potential for lost code.

Comment: Seems like a lot of effort for something that's probably quite rare. Switch your TFS repo to use git and being offline is no longer s problem.

Comment: @BrendanGreen that still won't resolve either the OneDrive sync problem or the access to uncommitted code problem plus i know such situations are rare, but as an enterprise primarily in research oriented projects, productivity loss due to rewriting the code gain is considered a higher cost than the device itself,

Comment: Thanks for your viewpoints, probably i fear too much for something which is rare.